# App.Mobile Project appears as (incompatible)

Tags: uno-platform

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.0.4

Starting from scratch a "Multi-Platform App (Uno Platform|net6)" project, closing the solution and reopening it, the "mobile" project is listed as "incompatible".

It happened to me on two different computers.

I run the "uno-check" and after installing the missing parts it tells me that everything is ok, but when I load the solution the mobile project continues with the same error.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you usuing?

Comment: Thanks!
VS -> Help -> About inform this (reduced) 

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.0.4
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.0.4+32014.148
Installed Version: Professional

Xamarin   17.0.0.343 d17-0@fb07a17
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android
Xamarin Templates   17.0.17 (9e779b0)

Xamarin.Android SDK   12.1.0.5 (d17-0/6b0e6b2)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support
    Mono: c633fe9
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-0@febb1367
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-0@a5194e9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET 6 mobile project template is only supported on Visual Studio 17.1 Preview 1 and later.

Comment: Thanks, that worked to solve the "incompatible" problem. I revolved instaling Visual Studio 2022 17.1 Preview 2.

Answer (score 0):

I leave the link where he explains that the problem is in the manifest of the packages.

[https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions/7833][1]